# Getting Audio issue in Youtube Live streaming in android application

Tags: android, audio, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am Developing an app in android live streaming. I am able to stream the live videos to the YouTube channel. But the problem was, getting no audio to that live streaming video.

My code will like below

```
 private static final int frequency= 44100;
     public void recordThread() {
            Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "recordThread");

            int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
            int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
            Log.i(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "AudioRecord buffer size: " + bufferSize);

            // 16 bit PCM stereo recording was chosen as example.
            AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency, channelConfiguration,
                    audioEncoding, bufferSize);
            recorder.startRecording();

            // Make bufferSize be in samples instead of bytes.
            bufferSize /= 2;
            short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
            while (!cancel) {
                int bufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                // Utils.Debug("bufferReadResult: " + bufferReadResult);
                if (bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    frameCallback.handleFrame(buffer, bufferReadResult);
                } else if (bufferReadResult < 0) {
                    Log.w(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "Error calling recorder.read: " + bufferReadResult);
                }
            }
            recorder.stop();

            Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "exit recordThread");
        }
```

please some suggest me the solution to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in github. There you will find a sample project(yasea) for audio encoding. Intermix those two projects, you will get the solution.